# Conversão de Valores View para Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso que `byte[]Descricao`, quando enviada para minha `view` exiba o texto como `string` para o usuário manipular dentro do `TextArea`, quando eu clicar
em salvar preciso que seja convertido novamente para `byte[]` para
que o `Controller` encontre o modelo enviado.

**Class:**

```
public class Carta {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual byte[] Descricao {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult MinhaCarta(int? Id){
     var carta = Id != 0 ? sessao.GetCarta(Id) : new Carta();

     View(carta);
}

public ActionResult SalvarCarta(Carta model){
     ...
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Carta
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Minha Carta"; 
}


@using ((Ajax.BeginForm("SalvarCarta", "Mensagem",  new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })))
{
    @Html.Hidden(m => m.Id)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Descricao)

    [SALVAR]
}
```

Seria possível validar via JavaScript talvez, dentro do `onClick` do Salvar?

Comment: Você pode criar um atributo `string` na `Model` e já enviar os dados convertidos para a `View`, e quando postar, converter novamente para `byte`.

Comment: Porque está fazendo assim? tem alguma obrigação!

Comment: Tem sim, estou tentando usar o padrão da empresa, porém o material que tenho não tem nenhum exemplo de como fazer isso @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Você salva com ORM?

Comment: Uso o NHibernate, se não me engano refere-se a um ORM certo? @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Deu certo?.....

Comment: Ainda não, entendi a ideia mas ta dando problema pra colocar isso na minha Class. Pois não deixa eu definir o "_descricao" sem o virtual e se eu colocar virtual diz que o "_descricao" não é valido para o item kk.. to pesquisando alguma maneira de fazer isso funcionar.. @VirgilioNovic

Comment: tem alguma coisa errado porque `_descricao` não precisa desse modificador!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça o seguinte então, na sua classe `Carta` modifique, para que quando o dado for recebido pela tela do usuário ele atribua no `array de bytes` automaticamente os valores e quando o `ORM` atribuir o valor para o `array de bytes` ele gera a informação em texto para ser mostrada na `View`:

***Classe:***

```
public class Carta
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    private byte[] _descricao;
    public virtual byte[] Descricao
    {
        get
        {
            return _descricao;
        }
        set
        {
            _descricao = value;
            _descricaoString =
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value);
        }
    }

    private String _descricaoString;
    public string DescricaoString
    {
        get
        {   
            return _descricaoString;
        }
        set
        {
            _descricaoString = value;
            Descricao = 
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        }
    }
}
```

gere a `View`com essas alterações que resultará nisso:

***View:***

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Carta</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DescricaoString)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DescricaoString)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescricaoString, "")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

com essas modificações o dado já vai pronto pra `View` e qualquer tentativa de alteração o dado é convertido para o formato de `array de bytes`, analisando isso se todo o mapeamento estiver correto e o campo `DescricaoString` tem que ser ignorado no seu modelo, para que o `ORM` não tente atualizar esse campo que é só mesmo uma forma de mostrar e recuperar informações:

***Modificações no Mapeamento dessa classe, adicionando:***

```
map.IgnoreProperty(p => p.DescricaoString);
```

<sub>Referencias:</sub>

- [C# – Criando classes, objetos, métodos construtores e acessores](https://blogdocodigo.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/c-criando-classes-objetos-metodos-construtores-e-acessores/)
- [Escrevendo atributos personalizados](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Byte arrays](https://www.dotnetperls.com/byte-array)
- [Mapping private properties](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties)
- [fluent-nhibernate](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate)
- [Classes e objetos](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/classes-e-objetos/)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. porém tive um pequeno problema para fazer funcionar mas pesquisei um pouco e achei a resposta, como estou usando o NHibernate na inicialização da minha session estava pedindo para declarar o 'virtual' em `private byte[] _descricao`.
Então, encontrei o codigo : [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741489/ignore-public-internal-fields-for-nhibernate-proxy) @MichaelGG .
Apenas adicionei a seguinte comando no `Fluently`:
`.ExposeConfiguration(x => x.Properties.Add("use_proxy_validator", "false"))`. E Pronto, funcionando perfeitamente!